Paused music starts playing automatically when I disconnect bluetooth earphones
On a Windows 11 laptop I have the following scenario

I have a tab with YouTube Music paused
I'm having a call with Meet with bluetooth earphones on (1MORE PistonBuds Pro, if that matters*)
I end the call, everything fine
I put the earphones in their case, ending the bluetooth connection
YouTube Music starts playing

How can I stop this last thing from happening?
The only suggestion I found was about disabling AutoPlay but my impression is that this doesn't have anything to do with AutoPlay (and it didn't work anyway).
I'm running Windows 11 Pro, version 23H2, build 22631.4037
* It may. I found out that the earphones have a feature that automatically stop and starts music when you put them in your ear or remove them. But I disabled it via the Android app. Also, I checked and I'm on the latest firmware update.

AutoPlay id usually a feature of automatically starting a movie/music/app from a DVD/CD/USB-drive so I agree it's unrelated to this issue. Do you have another pair of headphones to test with? Wired or Bluetooth? I'll try to test your scenario with my Win11 PC today

I wonder if YouTube triggers when you press headphone buttons to end call or accidentally touch them when putting them back in case?

@gregg about your first comment, I tried with another pair (some no-brand earphones) and they don't display the behavior.

@gregg about your second comment, if I simply get them out of their case, wait for them to connect and then just drop them inside without changing how I'm holding them I get the same behavior. Actually I noticed that sometimes the music starts, other times the play button does a loading animation and then goes back to a play button and the music doesn't start. So it looks like the act of putting them into their case is triggering something. I don't know if it matters, but they actually disconnect only when I close the case.

the earphones have a feature that automatically stop and starts music when you put them in your ear or remove them. But I disabled it via the Android app That affects the usage in the Android device where you performed that action only.

@ChanganAuto so is there a way to disable that in Windows as well? By the way, I would also like to point out that the "auto start/stop" behavior does not happen when I insert or remove the earbuds from my ears (which is what that feature is about), only when I put them into the case. Also, I did another experiment and when I put only one in the case the music starts; if then I put the other the music stops.

AFAIK there's no way to do the same in Windows other than the manufacturer provides such support.

Keen to know if you found a solution. I've had an issue that sounds the same. I'll be wearing my Sony WH-1000XM4 headphones in the office, pause the music and then might take the headphones off and forget about it. However as soon as the headphones power off, the music resumes and plays (sometimes at full volume) on my laptop, which is annoying when I'm at my laptop and downright embarrassing if I'm away from my desk... This has happened to me on 2 laptops on both Win 10 and 11

@pcdev nope. I'm just using a different set of earphones now. Sorry.
